# Image isn't adjusting properly with div

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, responsive-images

I'm having struggles trying to get my image to stretch out with my div. The width responds as expected but the height isn't reaching the bottom of the div as it expands in height as the window screen gets smaller.

HTML:

```
<div class="post-container">
        <div class="post-thumb">
            <img src="JKPWQF96-G01-121526-500px-650px.jpg" alt="client">
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
            <h1>Nathan Bayne</h1><br>
            <h2>Software Developer</h2><br>
            <p>This is dummy text!</p><br>
            <p>This is dummy text!</p><br>
            <p>This is dummy text!</p>
            <a href="#" class="button instagram"><span class="gradient"></span>Full Bio</a>
            <a href="#" class="button2 instagram"><span class="gradient"></span>Contact</a>
            <div class="social-buttons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>© Nathan Bayne, 2020. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Sets colour, width, border, height and margins of the main div where the image and text are within*/
.post-container {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 3% 15% 3% 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

/*Makes adjustments to width of the main image (covers 35% of post-container div)*/
.post-thumb {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

/*Makes adjustments to the image and allows the image to be outwith the div space to allow a higher quality image*/
.post-thumb img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: solid #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

This is what the screen currently looks like:

[image: Current Display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your demo, I think it's a problem with the **float** layout. I strongly recommended to you use the **[flex](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)** layout instead of the float. Try the following code:

Html：

```
<div class="layout">
    <div class="post-thumb">
        <img src="xxx.jpg" alt="client">
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS：

```
.layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.post-thumb {
  flex: 1;
}

.post-content {
  flex: 2;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  margin: 5% 5% 0% 5%;
}
```

Right now, our layout is like this, and I think this **a reasonable layout** for a website.
[image]

If you want to force the image to extend to the bottom, specifying the following css(force the image box to occupy the height of Copyright):

```
.post-thumb {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: -40px
}
```

**But I have to say this is a workaround**.
The correct way is to layout the website as the following, and then the image to fill the whole left naturally.
[image]

Comment: this is very close to getting it. It is about 30-50px off touching the bottom of the div. Currently working on it to see if i can get it working.

Comment: See my updated elaboration. You should consider the layout first and then your content (image is the content in this case)

Comment: brilliant mate. I've changed the -40px to -2.3% and that adjusts it accordingly with the div. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: cover;` for you image.
It fits the image with its container.

Comment: I have that already included within the code. I did expect that to originally work when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

As like Ali Bahaari, you can use object-fit cover to fit the image fully on the div, but there is a possibility of cropping of image in the left or right, you can use `object-fit: contain`, which contains your whole image.
If you `object-cover` use `object-position` property to start your image in the left or right or top or bottom

Comment: I have also tried used object-fit: contain; and it also doesn't seem to work. I also tried using your object position and it doesn't change anything.